# Improper Use of Geometric Formula

Tags: probability

Assume that every time you hear a song on the radio, the chance of it being your favorite song
is $2\%$. How many songs must you listen to so that the probability of hearing your favorite song
exceeds $90\%$?

**My initial approach was:**

This is a geometric distribution with probability of success $p=0.02$. Let the random variable $X$ be the number of songs heard BEFORE I hear my favorite song. For example, $X=3$ means I heard 3 mediocre songs before my favorite song. So we want,

$P(X=k)=(1-p)^kp > 0.9\\\\
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\Rightarrow (1-p)^k > 0.9/p\\\\
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\Rightarrow k(\log(1-p)) > \log(0.9/p)\\\\
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\Rightarrow k > \frac{\log(0.9/p)}{\log(1-p)}\\\\
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~= k > \frac{\log(0.9/0.02)}{\log(0.98)}\\ $

**The correct approach was:**

$P$(good song) $=0.02$

$P$(bad song) = $0.98$

$P$(n bad songs) = $0.98^n$

$P$(good song after n) = $1-(0.98)^n$

thus,

$1-(0.98)^n > 0.9 \Rightarrow n > \frac{\log{(1-0.9)}}{\log{0.98}}$

What did I do wrong in my initial approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are considering the probability that you hear *exactly* $k$ songs before the favourite, which is not greater than $2\%$ for all $k$, let alone $90\%$. This is illustrated if you evaluate the final expression for $k$ in your approach – it comes to the absurd $-188.423$.

Answer (score 1):

You want the value of $n$ such that the probability for hearing your favourite song **among** $n$ songs exceeds $90\%$.   Not only "at the end", but anywhere "among" them.

Alternatively: that the probability for *not* hearing your favourite song among those $n$ is at most $10\%$.

Thus:

$$(1-0.02)^n\leqslant (1-0.90)\\ n\log 0.98\leqslant \log 0.10\\\vdots\\ n\geqslant 114$$